# Outlook Web App *light* version

Tags: applications, browser, chrome-for-android, outlook

When I access my OWA site on my Android Chrome (Pixel 2), I always get the full version like the one on the desktop. How do I access the *light* version on my Android phone instead? On my iPhone, the light version is the default either using Chrome or Safari.

Comment: Tried [this](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2506626/outlook-web-app-opens-in-the-light-version-when-it-s-used-in-office-36)?

Comment: saw the option, clicked, saved, exited, relaunched, but same desktop version presented. the option is still checked but no light version.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Option in the Outlook Web OWA, then select "Outlook Web Version" , then uncheck the box that says "Use the light version of OutlookWeb App"